# no kernel log when plugging device

Tags: logging, kernel, rsyslog

I'd want to get informations about and USB keyboard that I've just plugged on my Linux host (shared USB device from a Host, using vmware).

Usually, I expect to see a message inside /var/log/kern.log, but nothing appears.

rsyslog is configured like this, seems fine:

```
root@shinwey# grep kern /etc/rsyslog.*
/etc/rsyslog.conf:module(load="imklog")   # provides kernel logging support
/etc/rsyslog.conf:kern.*                                -/var/log/kern.log
```

I tried to increase kernel verbosity without success:

```
root@shinwey:/var/log# echo 28 > /proc/sys/kernel/printk
root@shinwey:/var/log# cat  /proc/sys/kernel/printk
28      4       1       7
```

Do you have any hint why nothing appears and how to fix this ?

Best Regards,

Comment: After plugging it in, does the keyboard actually work?

Comment: yep keyboard works fine

Comment: Does something show in `/var/log/syslog`?

Comment: nope, nothing also in /var/log/syslog

Comment: Do you have a host system and a guest system running in a virtual machine? Are you plugging the keyboard to the host and expecting it to be logged in the guest (vmware) system?

Comment: yep, that's exactly the case. I've enabled the keyboard in the guest, and I used to see the kernel messages in the logs when doing this. But the kernel messages do not appear anymore, and I don't know why, cause I did not change anything in the configuration. Only one guest running at the same time.